# Protocol for "docker pull" command

Tags: image, http, docker

I am not sure what protocol does the "docker pull" or the "docker push " command use. When I try to access an image from a remote repository using the following convention

```
"docker pull http://my-repo/image-name:tag"
```

It fails with

```
 http://my-repo/image-name:tag is not a valid repository/tag
```

But the following command runs with no issues

```
"docker pull my-repo/image-name:tag"
```

I have a requirement that I need the `"http://"`prefix in the repo-name. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Usage: docker pull [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG] | [REGISTRY_HOST[:REGISTRY_PORT]/]NAME[:TAG]

According to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/), docker uses https by default, unless your private repo allows otherwise.

In the same docs you'll find

> A registry path is similar to a URL, but does not contain a protocol
>   specifier (https://).

Explicitly prefixing `http://` on your `docker pull` command is not a valid syntax.

Comment: This answer is answering the question and should be closed as doing so.